# Selenium Python : Click svg element to close form

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to close a form by clicking on a svg element. However, my code throws error.

```
<svg width="24" height="24" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<defs><path id="icon-close_svg__a" d="M0 1.5L1.5 0 8 6.5 14.5 0 16 1.5 9.5 8l6.5 6.5-1.5 1.5L8 9.5 1.5 16 0 14.5 6.5 8z"></path></defs>
<use xlink:href="#icon-close_svg__a" transform="translate(4 4)"></use>
</svg>
```

Here is my code :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[ @*[contains(., 'icon-close')]]").click()
```

Error:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.198)
```

I believe the error is because it does not get the svg element but the element within it. So how do I select svg through its sub - elements?

Comment: Could you give us the specific page?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA, here is the link : https://postmates.com/merchant/shawarma-stackz-miami?p=d9b4fae9-89fa-44dd-9fd6-a7e772a56e38